# base::url reads webpage but xml2::read_html gives 404 error

Tags: r, http-status-code-404, rvest, xml2

I've encountered a very strange problem while using `rvest`. This is one of the examples: https://politics.raisethemoney.com/cchristiansen. This pages opens normally in any web browser, and is open-able by `base::url`.

```
A connection with                                                              
description "https://politics.raisethemoney.com/cchristiansen"
class       "url-libcurl"                                     
mode        "r"                                               
text        "text"                                            
opened      "closed"                                          
can read    "yes"                                             
can write   "no"
```

When `xml2::read_html` is used, it gives a 404 error.

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

Tested on both Rstudio Cloud and a local machine (Windows 10). I'm baffled. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: `httr::content(httr::GET("https://politics.raisethemoney.com/cchristiansen"))` seems to work fine and gives an `html_document` as output (which IIRC is the same as `xml2` _should_ be doing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is looking for a specific header  in the request i.e.

```
'Accept' : ''
```

This needs to be provided in order for the request to be given 200 from server. This header is a default one within httr for example but I assume you don't have this with methods you are trying.

Here are some quick tests I ran with Python `requests` (somewhat similar to rvest):

[image]